# WPF can't read arguments passed

Tags: c#, wpf, command-line-arguments, custom-action

I am trying to get the command line arguments in WPF but it always returns `[]`. It's very strange I even tried to send argument via `cmd` but no success

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Args.ToString()); // returns Empty Array
        MessageBox.Show(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString()); // returns Empty Array

        if (e.Args.Length == 1 && e.Args[0] == "INSTALLER")
        {
            return;
        }

        // Create main application window, starting minimized if specified
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
```

**This is how I am passing Argument in CustomAction::**

[image]

**#Edit::**
I'm using simple VisualStudio installer, generating MSI files. **I want to run App after installation with some Arguments**

Comment: Your message box shows "[]"? I'd expect "System.String[]", because ToString returns the name of the type by default.

Comment: @SomeBody I mean to say it return `Empty Array` but it should show some `arg`

Comment: What exactly is CustomAction? What type of installer do you use? Wix?

Comment: @user2250152 see #Edit in ques.. I want to run the app after installation with Arg

Comment: I strongly doubt that `e.Args.ToString()` returns "Empty Array"

Comment: It seems a lot more likely to me that you are misinterpreting what is displayed by your `ToString()` calls, than that the API you're using is fundamentally broken. See duplicate for the correct way to display the contents of an array. Next time, consider using the debugger to actually _examine_ the object directly, rather than assuming that your own code written by you is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the OnStartup Method in App.cs, which has `StartupEventArgs` as a parameter.
Then just get the commandline arguments with `startupEventArgs.Args`, like so:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs startupEventArgs)
{
    MessageBox.Show(startupEventArgs.Args[0].ToString());
}
```

If you just print `startupEventArgs.Args.ToString()` to a Messagebox, it will print `System.String[]`. This is just the datatype of the array, but that doesn't mean its empty. Try to access it with a index or print `startupEventArgs.Args.Length`